# Problema de acentuação PHP

Tags: php, acentuação

Preciso resolver o problema de acentuação do seguinte código!

```
<?php

class SHIPPING_TRANSPORTAX extends ISC_SHIPPING
{
///////////////////////////////////////////////
            function SHIPPING_TRANSPORTAX(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->_name = "TTransporte da Loja (Somente na cidade de Itaja&iacute;-SC)";
            $this->_image = "transportax.gif";
            $this->_description = "O Produto &eacute; enviado pelo transporte da nossa loja";
            $this->_help = "Modulo de Entrega pelo transporte da loja";
            $this->_enabled = $this->CheckEnabled();
            $this->_countries = array("all");
            $this->_showtestlink = false;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
public function SetCustomVars()
{
    $this->_variables['displayname'] = array(
        'name'          => 'Entrega pelo transporte da loja.',
        'type'      => 'textbox',
        'help'      => 'Modulo de Entrega em domicilio.',
        'default'   => $this->GetName(),
        'savedvalue'    => array(),
        'required'  => true);

    $this->_variables['valorentrega'] = array(
        'name'          => 'Preco do frete',
        'type'      => 'textbox',
        'help'      => 'Valor da entrega.',
        'default'   => '0.00',
        'required'  => true);



}
/////////////////////////////////
function GetServiceQuotes()
{
    $QuoteList = array();
    $services = "Transporte da Loja (Somente na cidade de Itaja&iacute;-SC)";
    if(!is_array($services) && $services != "") {
        $services = array($services);
    }
    foreach($services as $service) {
        // Set the service type
        $this->_deliverytype = $service;

        // Next actually retrieve the quote
        $result = $this->GetQuote();

        // Was it a valid quote?
        if(is_object($result)) {
            $QuoteList[] = $result;
        // Invalid quote, log the error
        } else {
            foreach($this->GetErrors() as $error) {
                $GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_LOG']->LogSystemError(array('shipping', $this->_name), $this->_deliverytypes[$delivery_type].": " .GetLang('ShippingQuoteError'), $error);
            }
            $this->ResetErrors();
        }
    }
    return $QuoteList;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
function GetQuote(){

$this->_shippingcost = $this->GetValue("valorentrega");

    $fr_quote = new ISC_SHIPPING_QUOTE($this->GetId(), $this->GetName(), $this->_shippingcost, '', 2);
    return $fr_quote;


}
/////////////////////////////////////////////
}
?>
```

Comment: Qual o problema? Aonde esta exatamente o problema?

Comment: Melhore a descrição do problema?

Comment: -1. Não está claro o sugficiente

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser problema de localização do HTML que vai exibir isso... experimenta colocar tags de localização e codificação nele

```
    <html lang="pt-BR">

    <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
```

Comment: Como você entendeu o que ele está perguntando? A pergunta não está nada descritiva